# How to return the coordinates of a getLocation function, return latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, function, geolocation, return, latitude-longitude

I am attempting to build a weather API using the freeCodeCamp API for the weather project.

What I want to do is use the getLocation function to get the latitude and longitude and then return them as a variables that I can use to then concat to a URL.
By using the URL I can obtain the json information I need to output the Fahrenheit and any other info I need.
Since I require an https connection I am using codepen for testing purposes.

additional info:
    
Codepen:
    https://codepen.io/rogercodes/pen/gXvOoO
    
freeCodeCamp API:
    https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/

HTML

```
<html>
<head>

  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="css/quoteStyles.css"> -->
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="getWeather(finalLat,finalLon)">getWeather</button>
<p>What is</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>


<p id='geoAPI'>Geo API</p>
<p id="lan">Test Lan: </p>
 <p id='geo'>geoLocal</p><script>

 </script>
</body>
<script src="javascript/weatherTest.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="JSON/weather.json"></script> -->
```

Javascript

```
var api= "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?";
var googleApi="https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?
key=AIzaSyCOMzDSyP4RkXwp7mSiFiuAZroyrazU5eM";

var lat, lon;
var x= document.getElementById("geoLocal");
var tempX= document.getElementById("temp");
var geoLocal=document.getElementById("geo");
var xLat= document.getElementById("lat");
// Following functions will get the latitude and longitude

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        geoLocal.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this 
 browser.";
    }
}
var finalLat=finalCoords[0];
var finalLon=finalCoords[1];
function showPosition(position){
  geoLocal.innerHTML="Latitude:" + position.coords.latitude +
  "<br> Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
  lat= position.coords.latitude;
  lon=position.coords.longitude;
  var finalCoords=[lat,lon]
  return finalCoords;
}
showPosition(position);
console.log(api,lon);
xLat.innerHTML="testLat: " + finalCoords[0];
finalLat=finalCoords[0];
finalLon=finalCoords[1];

function getWeather(finalLat,finalLon){
  var completeApi=api+lon+"&"+lat;
  // lon="lon="+ position.coords.longitude;
  // lat='lat='+ position.coords.latitude;
  xLat.innerHTML="testLatitude: " +completeApi;

  return completeApi;
  }
getWeather(finalLat,finalLon);
```

The commented information below is the additional work I am going to be using to complete outputting the weather for any user location.

```
// var completeApi="getWeather(lat,lon)";
// JSON request for API to get temperature
// var ourRequest= new XMLHttpRequest();
// ourRequest.open('GET',completeApi);
// ourRequest.onload= function() {
//   if (ourRequest.status>= 200 && ourRequest.status<400){
//     var ourData= JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
//     renderHTML(ourData);
//     console.log("ourData",ourData);
// } else{
//   console.log("Connection Error, Please try again.")
// }
// };

// ourRequest.send();
// console.log(ourRequest)

// var jsonWeather= JSON.stringify(ourData);
// document.body.innerHTML=jsonWeather;
// function renderHTML(data){
//   var htmlString="";
//   for (i=0;i<data.lenth;i++){
//     htmlString=data[i].coord;
//     console.log(data[i].coord)
//     tempX.textContent= data;

//   }
//   // htmlString.textContent=data[0];
//   tempX.textContent= data;
//   // return data;
// }
// console.log(ourRequest)
// var geoLocation= document.getElementById("geoAPI");
// geoLocation.innerHTML=completeApi;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geolocation API is an asynchronous operation. It would be best to implement this usecase using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (if available ) or the [callback pattern](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/).

Basically the following asynchronous operations need to happen in order:

1. Get the current location using geolocation API
2. Get the weather data using an AJAX request
3. Make whatever DOM updates necessary to show the results

Sample Implementation using the callback pattern:

```js
// Helper to get the location from the browser
function getLocation(cb) {
  cb = (cb && typeof cb === 'function' && cb) || function() {};
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
      cb(null, [pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude]);
    });
  } else {
    cb(new Error('Browser does not support geolocation'));
  }
}


// Helper to make the AJAX call to the API
function getWeather(coords, cb) {
  cb = (cb && typeof cb === 'function' && cb) || function() {};
  // Build URL
  var url = 'https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=' + coords[0] + '&lon=' + coords[1];
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // TODO: Handle error cases
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // TODO: Handle possible parse exception
      cb(null, JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText));
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

// This gets triggered on clicking the button
function handleClick() {
  //1. Get the current location using geolocation API
  getLocation(function(err, coords) {
    if (err) {
      // Handle error, return early
      return;
    }

    // 2. Get the weather data using an AJAX request
    getWeather(coords, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        // Handle error, return early
        return;
      }
      // Data is available here. Update DOM/process as needed
      // 3. Make whatever DOM updates necessary to show the results
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="handleClick()">Get Weather Data</button>
```

Comment: Your answer works. Could you can explain what is the purpose of the following portion? I am mainly asking for help to explaining adding/passing the param cb.
      function getLocation(cb) {
           cb = (cb && typeof cb === 'function' && cb) || function() {};
           if (navigator.geolocation) {
             navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
              cb(null, [pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude]);
             });
  } else {
           cb(new Error('Browser does not support geolocation'));
         }
       }

Comment: It looks like the code snippet did not change correctly. I wanted to request an explanation of the first function after
// Helper to get the location from the browser

Comment: If you are referring to `cb = (cb && typeof cb === 'function' && cb) || function() {};`  It checks that the param is passed and that it's a function. If not, it uses an empty no-op function so the script does not fail. The function as a whole checks to see if the browser supports gelocation and invoke it if it is available. If it is not available, the callback is invoked with an error as the first parameter. You can test for that in the callback passed to it in `handleClick` and show a message to the user if they are using a browser which does not support geolocation

Comment: You could technically combine both `getLocation` and `getWeather` as one single function. I have separated it out in the interest of reusability in case location is being used in other places in the code